# TypeError: "instance[methodName] is not a function" - fabric js error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fabricjs

I was trying to connect two figures on canvas with the line and that line will stick to the figure so where figure moves on the canvas corresponding arrow will also move.

It is working the same way I am expecting but it is giving me error while I was generating a JSON by calling method `"rasterizeJSON()"`, it is not changing the object into a string while applying `JSON.stringify(objectName);`

> Error - TypeError: "instance[methodName] is not a function"
>   _toObjectwebpack-

```
export class WorkFlowEditorComponent {

@ViewChild('launch') launch: ElementRef;

REC_WIDTH = 60;
REC_HEIGHT = 30;
TRI_WIDTH = 10;
TRI_HEIGHT = 10;
disX;
disY;
_self = this;
start;
private canvas: any;
private props: any = {
    canvasFill: '#ffffff',
    canvasImage: '',
    id: null,
    name: null,
    opacity: null,
    fill: null,
    fontSize: null,
    lineHeight: null,
    charSpacing: null,
    fontWeight: null,
    fontStyle: null,
    textAlign: null,
    fontFamily: null,
    TextDecoration: ''
};

private textString: string;
private url: string = '';
private size: any = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 400
};

private json: any;
private globalEditor: boolean = false;
private textEditor: boolean = false;
private imageEditor: boolean = false;
private figureEditor: boolean = false;
private selected: any;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    //   ['object:moving'].forEach(this.addChildMoveLine);
    //setup front side canvas
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
        hoverCursor: 'pointer',
        selection: true,
        selectionBorderColor: 'blue'
    });


    var HideControls = {
        'tl': true,
        'tr': false,
        'bl': true,
        'br': true,
        'ml': true,
        'mt': true,
        'mr': true,
        'mb': true,
        'mtr': true
    };

    this.canvas.on({
        'object:moving': (e) => {
            this.addChildMoveLine(e);
            //console.log(e);
            //this.addDeleteBtn(e.target.oCoords.tr.x, e.target.oCoords.tr.y);
        },
        'object:modified': (e) => {
            //console.log("object modified");
            this.addDeleteBtn(e.target.oCoords.tr.x, e.target.oCoords.tr.y);
        },
        'object:selected': (e) => {
            // console.log("inside canvas selected");
            this.addChildMoveLine(e);
            this.addDeleteBtn(e.target.oCoords.tr.x, e.target.oCoords.tr.y);
            let selectedObject = e.target;
            console.log("printing selected object" + selectedObject);
            this.selected = selectedObject
            selectedObject.hasRotatingPoint = true;
            selectedObject.transparentCorners = false;

            // selectedObject.cornerColor = 'rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.7)';

            this.resetPanels();

            if (selectedObject.type !== 'group' && selectedObject) {

                this.getId();
                this.getOpacity();

                switch (selectedObject.type) {
                    case 'rect':
                    case 'circle':
                    case 'triangle':
                        this.figureEditor = true;
                        this.getFill();
                        break;
                    case 'i-text':
                        this.textEditor = true;
                        this.getLineHeight();
                        this.getCharSpacing();
                        this.getBold();
                        this.getFontStyle();
                        this.getFill();
                        this.getTextDecoration();
                        this.getTextAlign();
                        this.getFontFamily();
                        break;
                    case 'image':
                        console.log('image');
                        break;
                }
            }
        },
        'selection:cleared': (e) => {
            this.selected = null;
            this.resetPanels();
        }
    });

    this.canvas.setWidth(this.size.width);
    this.canvas.setHeight(this.size.height);

    // get references to the html canvas element & its context
    // this.canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
    // let canvasElement: any = document.getElementById('canvas');
    // console.log(canvasElement)
    // });

}

//method to connect arrow from one shape to another
addChild() {
    if (this.canvas.getActiveObject() == null) {
        console.log("inside add child if");
        return "getactiveobject is null (add child)";
    }
    this.canvas.addChild = {
        start: this.canvas.getActiveObject()
    };

    //for when addChild is clicked twice
    this.canvas.off({
        'object:selected': (e) => {
            this.addChildLine(e)
            console.log("move off" + e);
            //this.addDeleteBtn(e.target.oCoords.tr.x, e.target.oCoords.tr.y);
        },
    })

    this.canvas.on({
        'object:selected': (e) => {
            this.addChildLine(e)
            console.log("move line");
        },
    }
    );
}

calcArrowAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var angle = 0,
        x, y;

    console.log("arrow angle", x1, y1, x2, y2);
    x = (x2 - x1);
    y = (y2 - y1);

    if (x === 0) {
        angle = (y === 0) ? 0 : (y > 0) ? Math.PI / 2 : Math.PI * 3 / 2;
    } else if (y === 0) {
        angle = (x > 0) ? 0 : Math.PI;
    } else {
        angle = (x < 0) ? Math.atan(y / x) + Math.PI : (y < 0) ? Math.atan(y / x) + (2 * Math.PI) : Math.atan(y / x);
    }

    console.log("PI", Math.PI);
    return (angle * 180 / Math.PI + 90);
}

addChildLine(options) {
    this.canvas.off({
        'object:selected': (e) => {
            this.addChildLine(e)
            console.log("move line in off");
            //this.addDeleteBtn(e.target.oCoords.tr.x, e.target.oCoords.tr.y);
        },
    }
    )

    var fromObject = this.canvas.addChild.start;
    console.log(fromObject);
    var toObject = options.target;
    console.log(toObject);
    var from = fromObject.getCenterPoint();
    // console.log(from)
    var to = toObject.getCenterPoint();
    var fromX = from.x;
    var fromY = from.y;
    var toX = to.x;
    var toY = to.y;

    // var disX = REC_WIDTH/2 + TRI_WIDTH/2;
    // var disY = REC_HEIGHT/2 + TRI_HEIGHT/2;
    //var distanceX, distanceY;
    //calibrateLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY);

    var calibrateX = this.REC_WIDTH / 2 + this.TRI_WIDTH / 2;
    var calibrateY = this.REC_HEIGHT / 2 + this.TRI_HEIGHT / 2

    //storing and calculate x and y axis of the imagrd to be connected
    var distanceX, distanceY;

    if (fromX < toX) {
        distanceX = toX - fromX;
    } else {
        distanceX = fromX - toX;
    }

    if (fromY < toY) {
        distanceY = toY - fromY;
    } else {
        distanceY = fromY - toY;
    }

    if (distanceX > distanceY) {

        if (fromX < toX) {
            toX -= calibrateX;
        } else {
            toX += calibrateX;
        }
    } else {
        if (fromY < toY) {
            toY -= calibrateY;
        } else {
            toY += calibrateY;
        }
    }

    var line = new fabric.Line([fromX, fromY, toX, toY], {
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        selectable: false,
        fromObject: fromObject,
        toObject: toObject,
    });

    // leftover code that we might need but probably not
    /*
    centerX = (from.x + to.x)/2;
    centerY = (from.y + to.y)/2;
    deltaX = line.left - centerX;
    deltaY = line.top - centerY;
    */
    console.log(line.x1)
    line.triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
        left: line.x2,
        top: line.y2,
        angle: this.calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2),
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        lockScalingX: true,
        lockScalingY: true,
        lockRotation: true,
        pointType: 'arrow_start',
        width: this.TRI_WIDTH,
        height: this.TRI_HEIGHT,
        fill: 'red',
        selectable: false,
    });



    var Group = new fabric.Group([line, line.triangle]);
    // canvas.add(Group);
    var objs = [line, line.triangle];

    var add = new fabric.Group(objs);
    // this.extend(add, this.randomId());
    this.canvas.add(line, line.triangle);


    //this.canvas.add(add);
    //this.selectItemAfterAdded(add);
    //this.canvas.add(Group);
    // so that the line is behind the connected shapes
    line.sendToBack();

    // add a reference to the line to each object
    //console.log(fromObject.addChild);
    fromObject.addChild = fromObject.addChild || {};
    fromObject.addChild.lines = fromObject.addChild.lines || [];
    console.log(fromObject.addChild.lines);
    fromObject.addChild.lines.push(line);
    toObject.addChild = toObject.addChild || {};
    //console.log(toObject.addChild);
    toObject.addChild.lines = toObject.addChild.lines || [];
    console.log(toObject.addChild.lines);
    toObject.addChild.lines.push(line);

    // to remove line references when the line gets removed
    line.addChildRemove = function () {
        fromObject.addChild.lines.forEach(function (e, i, arr) {
            if (e === line)
                arr.splice(i, 1);
        });
    };

    // undefined instead of delete since we are anyway going to do this many times
    this.canvas.addChild = undefined;
}

addChildMoveLine(e) {
    var self = this;
    //console.log("inside child move line");
    // this.canvas.on({
    //     'object:moving': (e) => {
    // console.log("move");
    // console.log(e.target);

    // this.canvas.on(event, function(options) {
    var object = e.target;
    // console.log("addChildMoveLine");
    // udpate lines (if any)
    if (object.addChild && object.addChild.lines) {
        object.addChild.lines.forEach(function (line) {
            console.log(line.fromObject.getCenterPoint());
            var fcenter = line.fromObject.getCenterPoint(),
                fx = fcenter.x,
                fy = fcenter.y,
                tcenter = line.toObject.getCenterPoint(),
                tx = tcenter.x,
                ty = tcenter.y,
                xdis = self.REC_WIDTH / 2 + self.TRI_WIDTH / 2,
                ydis = self.REC_HEIGHT / 2 + self.TRI_HEIGHT / 2,
                horizontal = Math.abs(tx - line.x1) > Math.abs(ty - line.y1)
            line.set({
                'x1': fx,
                'y1': fy,
                'x2': tx + xdis * (horizontal ? (tx < line.x1 ? 1 : -1) : 0),
                'y2': ty + ydis * (horizontal ? 0 : (ty < line.y1 ? 1 : -1)),
            });
            //this.calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
            line.triangle.set({
                'left': line.x2, 'top': line.y2,
                'angle': self.calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
            });
        });
    }

    this.canvas.renderAll();

}

calibrateLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {

    var distanceX = 0;
    var distanceY = 0;

    // if (fromX < toX) {
    //     distanceX = toX - fromX;
    // } else {
    //     distanceX = fromX - toX;
    // }

    // if (fromY < toY) {
    //     distanceY = toY - fromY;
    // } else {
    //     distanceY = fromY - toY;
    // }

    if (distanceX > distanceY) {

        if (fromX < toX) {
            toX -= this.disX;
        } else {
            toX += this.disX;
        }
    } else {
        if (fromY < toY) {
            toY -= this.disY;
        } else {
            toY += this.disY;
        }
    }
}

addDeleteBtn(x, y) {
    $(".deleteBtn").remove();
    var btnLeft = x - 10;
    var btnTop = y - 10;
    // <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete element" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"
    //                     [disabled]="!selected" (click)="removeSelected();">

    //                 </button>
    var deleteBtn = ' <i class="fa fa-trash deleteBtn" aria-hidden="true" style="position:absolute;top:' + btnTop + 'px;left:' + btnLeft + 'px;cursor:pointer;width:20px;height:20px; " onclick=alert("hrllo")></i>';
    $(".canvas-container").append(deleteBtn);
}


/*------------------------Block elements------------------------*/

//Block "Size"

changeSize(event: any) {
    console.log("changeSize")
    this.canvas.setWidth(this.size.width);
    this.canvas.setHeight(this.size.height);
}

//Block "Add text"

addText() {
    let textString = this.textString;
    let text = new fabric.IText(textString, {
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        fontFamily: 'helvetica',
        angle: 0,
        fill: '#000000',
        scaleX: 0.5,
        scaleY: 0.5,
        fontWeight: '',
        hasRotatingPoint: true
    });
    this.extend(text, this.randomId());
    this.canvas.add(text);
    this.selectItemAfterAdded(text);
    this.textString = '';
}

//Block "Add images"

getImgPolaroid(event: any, src: any) {
    console.log("inside polaroid method");
    let el = event.target;

    console.log(src);
    fabric.Image.fromURL(src, (image) => {
        image.set({
            left: 10,
            top: 10,
            angle: 0,
            padding: 10,
            cornersize: 10,
            //hasRotatingPoint: true,
            peloas: 12,
            hasControls: false
        });
        image.setWidth(50);
        image.setHeight(50);
        this.extend(image, this.randomId());
        this.canvas.add(image);
        this.selectItemAfterAdded(image);
    });
}

//Block "Upload Image"

addImageOnCanvas(url) {
    if (url) {
        fabric.Image.fromURL(url, (image) => {
            image.set({
                left: 10,
                top: 10,
                angle: 0,
                padding: 10,
                cornersize: 10,
                hasRotatingPoint: true
            });
            image.setWidth(200);
            image.setHeight(200);
            this.extend(image, this.randomId());
            this.canvas.add(image);
            this.selectItemAfterAdded(image);
        });
    }
}

readUrl(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            this.url = event.target['result'];
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
}

removeWhite(url) {
    this.url = '';
};

//Block "Add figure"

addFigure(figure) {
    let add: any;
    switch (figure) {
        case 'rectangle':
            add = new fabric.Rect({
                width: 60, height: 30, left: 100, top: 100, angle: 0,
                fill: '#ffffff',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                hasControls: false
            });
            break;
        case 'square':
            add = new fabric.Rect({
                width: 50, height: 50, left: 10, top: 10, angle: 0,
                fill: '#ffffff',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                hasControls: false
            });
            break;
        case 'triangle':
            add = new fabric.Rect({
                left: 100, top: 100, width: 20, height: 20, angle: 45,

                fill: '#ffffff',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                hasControls: false
            });
            break;
        case 'circle':
            add = new fabric.Circle({
                radius: 20, left: 10, top: 10,
                fill: '#ffffff',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 1,
                hasControls: false
            });
            break;
        case 'line':
            var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
                width: 10,
                height: 15,
                fill: 'red',
                left: 235,
                top: 65,
                angle: 90
            });

            var line = new fabric.Line([50, 100, 200, 100], {
                left: 75,
                top: 70,
                stroke: 'red'
            });
            var objs = [line, triangle];

            add = new fabric.Group(objs);
            break;

    }
    this.extend(add, this.randomId());
    this.canvas.add(add);
    this.selectItemAfterAdded(add);
}

/*Canvas*/

cleanSelect() {
    this.canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch().renderAll();
}

selectItemAfterAdded(obj) {

    this.canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch().renderAll();
    this.canvas.setActiveObject(obj);
}

setCanvasFill() {

    if (!this.props.canvasImage) {
        this.canvas.backgroundColor = this.props.canvasFill;
        this.canvas.renderAll();
    }
}

extend(obj, id) {

    obj.toObject = (function (toObject) {
        return function () {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                id: id,
                name: name
            });
        };
    })(obj.toObject);
}

setCanvasImage() {
    console.log("setCanvasImage");
    let self = this;
    if (this.props.canvasImage) {
        this.canvas.setBackgroundColor({ source: this.props.canvasImage, repeat: 'repeat' }, function () {
            // self.props.canvasFill = '';
            self.canvas.renderAll();
        });
    }
}

randomId() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 1;
}

/*------------------------Global actions for element------------------------*/

getActiveStyle(styleName, object) {

    object = object || this.canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return '';

    return (object.getSelectionStyles && object.isEditing)
        ? (object.getSelectionStyles()[styleName] || '')
        : (object[styleName] || '');
}


setActiveStyle(styleName, value, object) {

    object = object || this.canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return;

    if (object.setSelectionStyles && object.isEditing) {
        var style = {};
        style[styleName] = value;
        object.setSelectionStyles(style);
        object.setCoords();
    }
    else {
        object.set(styleName, value);
    }

    object.setCoords();
    this.canvas.renderAll();
}


getActiveProp(name) {

    var object = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return '';

    return object[name] || '';
}

setActiveProp(name, value) {

    var object = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return;
    object.set(name, value).setCoords();
    this.canvas.renderAll();
}

clone() {
    let activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObject(),
        activeGroup = this.canvas.getActiveGroup();

    if (activeObject) {
        let clone;
        switch (activeObject.type) {
            case 'rect':
                clone = new fabric.Rect(activeObject.toObject());
                break;
            case 'circle':
                clone = new fabric.Circle(activeObject.toObject());
                break;
            case 'triangle':
                clone = new fabric.Triangle(activeObject.toObject());
                break;
            case 'i-text':
                clone = new fabric.IText('', activeObject.toObject());
                break;
            case 'image':
                clone = fabric.util.object.clone(activeObject);
                break;
        }
        if (clone) {
            clone.set({ left: 10, top: 10 });
            this.canvas.add(clone);
            this.selectItemAfterAdded(clone);
        }
    }
}

getId() {
    //console.log("getId");
    this.props.id = this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject().id;
}

setId() {
    console.log("setId");
    let val = this.props.id;
    let complete = this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject();
    console.log(complete);
    this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject = () => {
        complete.id = val;
        return complete;
    };
}

setName() {
    console.log("setName");
    let val = this.props.name;
    let complete = this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject();
    console.log(complete);
    this.canvas.getActiveObject().toObject = () => {
        complete.name = val;
        return complete;
    };
}

getOpacity() {
    this.props.opacity = this.getActiveStyle('opacity', null) * 100;
}

setOpacity() {
    this.setActiveStyle('opacity', parseInt(this.props.opacity) / 100, null);
}

getFill() {
    this.props.fill = this.getActiveStyle('fill', null);
}

setFill() {
    this.setActiveStyle('fill', this.props.fill, null);
}

getLineHeight() {
    console.log("getLineHeight");
    this.props.lineHeight = this.getActiveStyle('lineHeight', null);
}

setLineHeight() {
    this.setActiveStyle('lineHeight', parseFloat(this.props.lineHeight), null);
}

getCharSpacing() {
    this.props.charSpacing = this.getActiveStyle('charSpacing', null);
}

setCharSpacing() {
    this.setActiveStyle('charSpacing', this.props.charSpacing, null);
}

getFontSize() {
    this.props.fontSize = this.getActiveStyle('fontSize', null);
}

setFontSize() {
    this.setActiveStyle('fontSize', parseInt(this.props.fontSize), null);
}

getBold() {
    this.props.fontWeight = this.getActiveStyle('fontWeight', null);
}

setBold() {
    this.props.fontWeight = !this.props.fontWeight;
    this.setActiveStyle('fontWeight', this.props.fontWeight ? 'bold' : '', null);
}

getFontStyle() {
    this.props.fontStyle = this.getActiveStyle('fontStyle', null);
}

setFontStyle() {
    this.props.fontStyle = !this.props.fontStyle;
    this.setActiveStyle('fontStyle', this.props.fontStyle ? 'italic' : '', null);
}


getTextDecoration() {
    this.props.TextDecoration = this.getActiveStyle('textDecoration', null);
}

setTextDecoration(value) {
    let iclass = this.props.TextDecoration;
    if (iclass.includes(value)) {
        iclass = iclass.replace(RegExp(value, "g"), "");
    } else {
        iclass += ` ${value}`
    }
    this.props.TextDecoration = iclass;
    this.setActiveStyle('textDecoration', this.props.TextDecoration, null);
}

hasTextDecoration(value) {
    return this.props.TextDecoration.includes(value);
}


getTextAlign() {
    this.props.textAlign = this.getActiveProp('textAlign');
}

setTextAlign(value) {
    this.props.textAlign = value;
    this.setActiveProp('textAlign', this.props.textAlign);
}

getFontFamily() {
    this.props.fontFamily = this.getActiveProp('fontFamily');
}

setFontFamily() {
    this.setActiveProp('fontFamily', this.props.fontFamily);
}

/*System*/


removeSelected() {
    console.log("removeSelected");
    let activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObject(),
        activeGroup = this.canvas.getActiveGroup();

    if (activeObject) {
        this.canvas.remove(activeObject);
        // this.textString = '';
    }
    else if (activeGroup) {
        let objectsInGroup = activeGroup.getObjects();
        this.canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        let self = this;
        objectsInGroup.forEach(function (object) {
            self.canvas.remove(object);
        });
    }
}

bringToFront() {
    console.log("bringToFront");
    let activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObject(),
        activeGroup = this.canvas.getActiveGroup();

    if (activeObject) {
        activeObject.bringToFront();
        // activeObject.opacity = 1;
    }
    else if (activeGroup) {
        let objectsInGroup = activeGroup.getObjects();
        this.canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        objectsInGroup.forEach((object) => {
            object.bringToFront();
        });
    }
}

sendToBack() {

    let activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObject(),
        activeGroup = this.canvas.getActiveGroup();

    if (activeObject) {
        activeObject.sendToBack();
        // activeObject.opacity = 1;
    }
    else if (activeGroup) {
        let objectsInGroup = activeGroup.getObjects();
        this.canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        objectsInGroup.forEach((object) => {
            object.sendToBack();
        });
    }
}

confirmClear() {
    console.log("confirmClear");
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        this.canvas.clear();
    }
}

rasterize() {
    console.log("rasterize");
    if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
        alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
    }
    else {
        console.log(this.canvas.toDataURL('png'))
        //window.open(this.canvas.toDataURL('png'));
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = this.canvas.toDataURL('png')
        var w = window.open("");
        w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
    }
}

rasterizeSVG() {
    console.log("rasterizeSVG");
    console.log(this.canvas.toSVG())
    // window.open(
    //   'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' +
    //   encodeURIComponent(this.canvas.toSVG()));
    // console.log(this.canvas.toSVG())
    // var image = new Image();
    // image.src = this.canvas.toSVG()
    var w = window.open("");
    w.document.write(this.canvas.toSVG());
};


saveCanvasToJSON() {
    let json = JSON.stringify(this.canvas);
    localStorage.setItem('Kanvas', json);
    console.log('json');
    console.log(json);

}

loadCanvasFromJSON() {
    let CANVAS = localStorage.getItem('Kanvas');
    console.log('CANVAS');
    console.log(CANVAS);

    // and load everything from the same json
    this.canvas.loadFromJSON(CANVAS, () => {
        console.log('CANVAS untar');
        console.log(CANVAS);

        // making sure to render canvas at the end
        this.canvas.renderAll();

        // and checking if object's "name" is preserved
        console.log('this.canvas.item(0).name');
        console.log(this.canvas);
    });

};

rasterizeJSON() {
    console.log("inside rasterize json method");
    console.log(this.canvas);
    try {
        this.json = JSON.stringify(this.canvas);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    //below line used for storing json locally on browser
    localStorage.setItem("Kanvas", this.json);
}

resetPanels() {
    console.log("resetPanels");

    // this.launch.nativeElement.click();
    this.textEditor = false;
    this.imageEditor = false;
    this.figureEditor = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: which version are you using? and use `this.json = this.canvas.toJSON()` not `this.json = JSON.stringify(this.canvas);`

Comment: @Durga I am still getting the same error after changing to "this.json = this.canvas.toJSON()" and angular version - 6 and fabric version - 1.7.22.

Comment: `_toObjectwebpack` is this from fabricjs? line number?

Comment: @Durga this is exact error with line numbers - http://prntscr.com/k0d0in

Comment: Why you are doing this`var fromObject = this.canvas.addChild.start;
    console.log(fromObject);
    var toObject = options.target;
`?

Comment: @Durga It is used to connect one figure to another figure so "var fromObject = this.canvas.addChild.start" adds child to it as shown in screenshot. http://prntscr.com/k0h83k

Comment: `toObject` is a method is used for serialisation, so use other name instaed of toObject

Comment: @Durga After changing name is also not working

Comment: Can you make simple snippet/fiddle stating your issue?